# External screens with Matrox DualHead2Go working in Linux?

Tags: external-monitor

I would like to know if a DualHead2GO would work in Linux, to have two external screens attached to it and to the VGA/DVI of my laptop:

http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/

The model number below:

```
18ea:0004 Matrox Graphics
```

According to the other ids I found on http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids , my model is probably a DualHead2Go Digital Edition:

```
18ea  Matrox Graphics, Inc.
    0002  DualHead2Go [Analog Edition]
    0004  TripleHead2Go [Digital Edition]
```

Extended print out of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 18ea:0003 Matrox Graphics, Inc. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.01
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x18ea Matrox Graphics, Inc.
  idProduct          0x0003 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 
  iProduct                2 
  iSerial                 4 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           41
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         3 Human Interface Device
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 No Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 None
      iInterface              0 
        HID Device Descriptor:
          bLength                 9
          bDescriptorType        33
          bcdHID               1.01
          bCountryCode            0 Not supported
          bNumDescriptors         1
          bDescriptorType        34 Report
          wDescriptorLength      34
         Report Descriptors: 
           ** UNAVAILABLE **
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               1
```

Comment: maybe this thread will give you some ideas - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1744124

Comment: Is this something specific to Matrox hardware or generic to many manufacturers?

Answer (score 1):

As [Fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom) pointed out, [Cyclops_](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=83076) got it to work ([see](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1744124)) by updating the firmware and changing the settings under Windows.